# Regarding the Manual NAT in Cisco ASA

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

I have cisco ASA 5515-x running version 9.2.  I want to port forward the request on 80 to 9006 which is of my DVR.

I did this :

```
object network obj-10.10.26.6
  host 10.10.26.6
object network obj-203.156.213.173
  host 203.156.213.173
object service port-80
  service tcp source eq 80
object service port-9006
  service tcp destination eq 9006

nat (inside,public-IP) source static obj-10.10.26.6 obj-203.156.213.173 service port-80 port-9006
```

I get this following error when I do port forwarding in the pool IP:

```
pac in public-IP tcp 8.8.8.8 12345 203.156.213.173 9006
```

Result:

```
input-interface: Public-IP
input-status: up
input-line-status: up
output-interface: Public-IP
output-status: up
output-line-status: up
Action: drop

Drop-reason: (nat-no-xlate-to-pat-pool) Connection to PAT address without pre-existing xlate
```

What am i doing wrong here? Why am i getting this error: "Drop-reason: (nat-no-xlate-to-pat-pool) Connection to PAT address without pre-existing xlate.

Actually, 201.135.201.73 is my Public IP and 203.156.213.173 is my pool IP that ISP has given and it is routable to my public ip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
no nat (inside,public-IP) source static obj-10.10.26.6 obj-203.156.213.173 service port-80 port-9006

object network obj-10.10.26.6
  host 10.10.26.6
  nat (inside,public-IP) static 203.156.213.173 service tcp port-80 port-9006
```

(or something similar, I'm doing this from memory).

**Or**, as I'm *guessing* that there is another (dynamic) nat statement *before* your static nat (but I don't have enough reputation yet to ask you in the comments, duh!), re-arrange the order so that the static comes first.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using source NAT then the ports should be set to source.

```
object service port-9006
 service tcp source eq 9006
```

Clear the translation table.

```
clear xlate
```

Comment: Hello Mark. .... But opening certain ports for certain service in firewall is part of destination NAT, right?

Comment: @de.walkar I see what you're saying... but it doesn't work like that. You're thinking because traffic is going to a server that it's destination NAT. Src/dst NAT depends on how you've set up your NAT statement. If you're modifying src address.. its src NAT. If you're modifying dst address, its dst NAT. On the ASA you can use either src or dst NAT and it will have the same effect. (IE you'll be able to reach it externally via pub IP). I usually use destination NAT on the ASA because its what makes sense in my head in regards to traffic flow. On IOS I use source NAT as I find it easier.

Comment: @de.walkar also, NAT doesn't exactly open ports. It just tells the FW where to send the traffic that arrives on this port. The ACL does the opening ports part. Generally, if you do one without the other, it won't work... Unless your ACL allows all traffic or something.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Yet this thing really bothers me. Can't understand it completely. In Fortigate, virtual IP works on destination NAT, right? Similarly, i thought opening port for certain task was part of destination NAT as remote user coming from public address have to get inside. For me source NAT was for internal users to go out to the internet. @Mark i am going to ask another question regarding this NAT, Can you please answer me there?